# POI databases for France, Spain, Italy

Tags: france, italy, spain, gps-navigation, alps

Planing trip to Europe. Does anybody can share or point KLM/KMZ/GPX or any other format with points of interest of Spain, France, whole region of Alps and Italy.

Comment: Vico, this kind of question, (sharing database) is not within the  limits of this site. If you edit your question so you ask for where to find POI online or a place to get them from others, it can be re-opened. But be aware that you ask for a huge area and that will make it too broad unless you adjust that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about traveling but asking for data.

Comment: Possibly try [opendata.se].